# What is the order that rd command processes files and folders

Tags: windows, command-prompt, delete-file

I am a bit troubled these days because I just started deleting C:/ on a production server. 
I just wanted to remove c:/$Recycle.bin to clean some disk space.
But when I attempted to type $, I accidentally pressed Enter instead of shift, because these are very close buttons on my keyboard.

So the command went to delete C:/ .... :( Luckily, I didn't run the cmd with administrator rights and I only removed a few GB because of permissions. 
I can recover the wasted files because the machine is protected with backups.
But how may I know what files have been deleted and what havn't?
Does anybody know in what order RD command (remove directory) processes the files / folders ? Alphabetically  or...

I'd be happy if someone can help.

Comment: Think better of using (too powerful) [`RD` command](http://ss64.com/nt/rd.html). I'd avoid using it on a _production_ server…

Comment: This isn't documented so you can't entirely depend on it, but on an NTFS volume it does it alphabetically.  I'm also pretty sure that the directory traversal is depth-first, but I'm not sure about files - it might delete all files from a folder before entering the subfolders.